# Pointer to device array inside host struct

Tags: struct, cuda

I'm trying to create a struct that will hold both the host and device arrays in one place and should reside on the host. I later intend expand it to be a element of a linked list. The basic struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct Data{
    double *h;
    double *d;
} Data;
```

Where *h points to an array of doubles on the host and *d points to an array of doubles on the device.

There are various answers on SO about copying whole structs to the the device ([CUDA cudaMemcpy Struct of Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598021/cuda-cudamemcpy-struct-of-arrays/31599025#comment51148602_31598021)) but none of them quite do what I need. I have the following code but keep getting illegal memory access errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "cuda.h"

/*
* CUDA Error stuff
*/

static void HandleError( cudaError_t err,
                         const char *file,
                         int line ) {
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        printf( "%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString( err ),
                file, line );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
#define HANDLE_ERROR( err ) (HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))


#define HANDLE_NULL( a ) {if (a == NULL) { \
                            printf( "Host memory failed in %s at line %d\n", \
                                    __FILE__, __LINE__ ); \
                            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );}}

//malloc error code
int errMsg(const char *message, int errorCode)
{
    printf("%s\n", message);
    return errorCode;
}

typedef struct Data{
    double *h;
    double *d;
} Data;

__global__ void kernel(Data *d)
{
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(tid<100){
        d->d[tid] = 2;
    }

}

int main()
{
    Data *d;
    d = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));

    d->h = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*100);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**) &(d->d), 100*sizeof(double)) );

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        d->h[i] = i;
    }

    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(d->d, d->h, 100*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    printf("%f\n", d->h[1]);

    kernel<<<1, 102>>>(d);

    printf("done\n");

    {
    cudaError_t cudaerr = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaerr != cudaSuccess)
        printf("kernel launch failed with error \"%s\"->\n",
               cudaGetErrorString(cudaerr));
    }

    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(d->h, d->d, 100*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
    printf("%f\n", d->h[99]);


    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
1.000000
done
kernel launch failed with error "an illegal memory access was encountered"->
an illegal memory access was encountered in linkedListGPU.cu at line 77
```

I suspect I have just messed up my pointers a bit. The error handling code is from the Wiley introduction to CUDA book, if there code is not allowed on here I'll remove it.

Thanks.

Comment: You are passing a host pointer to the device and trying to access it within the kernel. That obviously isn't ever going to work

Comment: Thank you, just changing the kernel call to (d->d) and tweaking the kernel code fixed it. Sorry about that, I've been getting in a muddle with structs on the device at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `d` itself is a pointer to a host-allocated struct (where the `d` and `h` pointers are contained.  When you pass the `d` struct pointer to the kernel like so:

```
kernel<<<1, 102>>>(d);
                   ^
                   this is a pointer to memory on the host
```

and then attempt to dereference that pointer in device code here:

```
    d->...;
     ^ 
     This operator dereferences the pointer to the left of it
```

you get an illegal memory access.

There are at least 2 obvious ways to fix this:

1. Pass the struct by value instead of by pointer.

Here is an example:

```
$ cat t1311.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "cuda.h"

/*
* CUDA Error stuff
*/

static void HandleError( cudaError_t err,
                         const char *file,
                         int line ) {
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        printf( "%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString( err ),
                file, line );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
#define HANDLE_ERROR( err ) (HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))


#define HANDLE_NULL( a ) {if (a == NULL) { \
                            printf( "Host memory failed in %s at line %d\n", \
                                    __FILE__, __LINE__ ); \
                            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );}}

//malloc error code
int errMsg(const char *message, int errorCode)
{
    printf("%s\n", message);
    return errorCode;
}

typedef struct Data{
    double *h;
    double *d;
} Data;

__global__ void kernel(Data d)
{
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(tid<100){
        d.d[tid] = 2;
    }

}

int main()
{
    Data d;

    d.h = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*100);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**) &(d.d), 100*sizeof(double)) );

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        d.h[i] = i;
    }

    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(d.d, d.h, 100*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    printf("%f\n", d.h[1]);

    kernel<<<1, 102>>>(d);

    printf("done\n");

    {
    cudaError_t cudaerr = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaerr != cudaSuccess)
        printf("kernel launch failed with error \"%s\"->\n",
               cudaGetErrorString(cudaerr));
    }

    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(d.h, d.d, 100*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
    printf("%f\n", d.h[99]);


    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t1311 t1311.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1311
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
1.000000
done
2.000000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

2. Make a device copy of the struct that the `d` host pointer points to:

Here is an example:

```
$ cat t1311.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "cuda.h"

/*
* CUDA Error stuff
*/

static void HandleError( cudaError_t err,
                         const char *file,
                         int line ) {
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        printf( "%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString( err ),
                file, line );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
#define HANDLE_ERROR( err ) (HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))


#define HANDLE_NULL( a ) {if (a == NULL) { \
                            printf( "Host memory failed in %s at line %d\n", \
                                    __FILE__, __LINE__ ); \
                            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );}}

//malloc error code
int errMsg(const char *message, int errorCode)
{
    printf("%s\n", message);
    return errorCode;
}

typedef struct Data{
    double *h;
    double *d;
} Data;

__global__ void kernel(Data *d)
{
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(tid<100){
        d->d[tid] = 2;
    }

}

int main()
{
    Data *d, *dev_d;
    d = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&dev_d, sizeof(Data)));
    d->h = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*100);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**) &(d->d), 100*sizeof(double)) );

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        d->h[i] = i;
    }

    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(d->d, d->h, 100*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(dev_d, d, sizeof(Data), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    printf("%f\n", d->h[1]);

    kernel<<<1, 102>>>(dev_d);

    printf("done\n");

    {
    cudaError_t cudaerr = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaerr != cudaSuccess)
        printf("kernel launch failed with error \"%s\"->\n",
               cudaGetErrorString(cudaerr));
    }

    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(d->h, d->d, 100*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
    printf("%f\n", d->h[99]);


    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t1311 t1311.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1311
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
1.000000
done
2.000000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

As an aside, you can follow the method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277365/unspecified-launch-failure-on-memcpy/27278218#27278218) to carry your debug process a bit farther.