# CUDA Binding into the Struct of Arrays

Tags: arrays, struct, binding, cuda

I need a clarification about the code given in the answer to the topic:
[CUDA cudaMemcpy Struct of Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31599025/681865).

Both dev_s and dev_arr1(2 and 3) are allocated in the device. Why is the flag cudaMemcpyHostToDevice used? It should be cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice.

The code is reported below.

```
// NOTE: Binding pointers with dev_s
cudaMemcpy(&(dev_s->arr1), &dev_arr1, sizeof(dev_s->arr1),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(&(dev_s->arr2), &dev_arr2, sizeof(dev_s->arr2),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(&(dev_s->arr3), &dev_arr3, sizeof(dev_s->arr3),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Comment: Is it C++? Please tag accordingly

Comment: Yes. But it is the same for C. See https://devblogs.nvidia.com/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/ . The function launch contains this line: cudaMemcpy(&(d_elem->name), &d_name, sizeof(char*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice). But both d_elem and d_name are allocated inside the device by means of a cudamalloc.

Answer (score 2):

> Both dev_s and dev_arr1(2 and 3) are allocated in the device.

Correct.

> Why is the flag cudaMemcpyHostToDevice used? It should be
>   cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice.

Incorrect.

That code is copying the pointer *values* of `dev_arr1`, `dev_arr2`, and `dev_arr3` from the host to the device. The addresses themselves are addresses in GPU memory, but the address values are stored in host memory, not device memory.