# Cuda copy pointer to arbitrary value

Tags: pointers, cuda, memcpy

say i have class like this

```
class TheBox{
public:
   int value1;
   int value2;

   int **p;
   int size;
   int result;

   int test(){
     result = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        result += *p[i];
     }
     return result;
   }
};
```

and i use it like this

```
int main(){

TheBox b;
b.value1 = 5;
b.value2 = 7;
b.size = 10;
b.p = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*b.size);

b.p[0] = &b.value1;
b.p[1] = &b.value1;
b.p[2] = &b.value2;
b.p[3] = &b.value1;
b.p[4] = &b.value1;
b.p[5] = &b.value2;
b.p[6] = &b.value2;
b.p[7] = &b.value1;
b.p[8] = &b.value1;
b.p[9] = &b.value1;

cout << b.host() << endl; //should output 56
b.value2 = 8;
cout << b.host() << endl; //should output 59

}
```

My question is how do i do cudaMemCpy for object "b"?

The problem occurs when trying to copy array "p" i have to know beforehand whether it contains value1 or value2.

Is there a way to correctly do cudaMemcpy for object "b" without this information?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to correctly do `cudaMemcpy` for object "b" without
>   this information?

In a word, no. And it isn't even obvious what "correctly do `cudaMemcpy`" would even mean in this context, given that the contents of the array of pointers contains host addresses and, therefore, could only be correctly set after a instance of the class had already been established in GPU memory.

The only possible way to do this that makes any sense would be to *construct* an instance in memory which is accessible to the GPU directly. You could do this with Unified Memory (see [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/) for an example), or by building a copy of the device structure in host memory and copying it to the device (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31598021/681865) for one approach).